# Error: Evaluating a math expression given in string form in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I want to evaluate a math expression from a string using `Scriptmanager` in android studio. I have successfully imported library [Jsr223](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ejrz.png). Now I am able to import following libraries required

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
```

Now when I do following code

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
String foo = "40+2";
ans = engine.eval(foo);
```

I get error at 
`ans = engine.eval(foo);`

> unhandled exception : javax.script.ScriptException. ans datatype is
>   int.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a06xn.png)

Using Android Studio 1.5.1 .

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace.

Comment: added a image. @CommonsWare

Answer (score 1):

```
try 
{
    int ans= (int) engine.eval(foo);
    System.out.printf("%d \n", ans);
} catch (ScriptException e) 
{   e.printStackTrace();   }
```

This does the job.  Notice the try/catch, the `int` declaration, and the casting to an `int`.

Comment: Thanks. Error is gone. But this is not working in my app. Crash the app.

Comment: By "crash the app" you mean the app just freezes and then you get the "Unfortunately, ... has stopped working" message?

Comment: Actually, try to comment out the `System.out.printf("%d \n, ans);` statement.  Not sure if that will help but I didn't realize you're working on Android (I just did it in Eclipse), so it may.  It's worth a try.  Let me know how it goes...

Comment: K, my AndroidStudio doesn't recognize JSR223 (although Eclipse does).  I'll have to play about with it and see what I can find.  Hopefully someone else can help in the mean time.